# Julia - How Julia processes a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, julia

I'm just starting to learn Julia. I'm using JuliaBox (browser based session).

Seems like most of the shell commands (in BASH works) in Julia's shell.

But, I didn't get why in BASH Shell/Julia shell, it didn't print $c (in the example below) first time but it works later on (after I did some operation on $v variable). How's Julia shell processes this behavior?

[image]

PS: I know if I want to print $c first time, I have to use `echo $((c))`

Comment: JuliaBox just drops you into a `bash` shell, so you are using pure `bash` commands in this example. Typing `julia` starts the Julia REPL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like the normal bash behaviour. `((...))` is used for arithmetic evaluation, without it, everything on the right hand side is a string. `$((...))` does arithmetic expansion, which means it expands to the result of the arithmetic expression. See `man bash`.